# In memory Database to test mysql database operation API using in memory database with maven

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, junit, hsqldb

I have to test some api using JUnit test cases. Actually I have some simple JDBC database connection with API code to retrieve data from MYSQL database.
   But I need one inmemory databases to test the correctness of code. I am using maven.
   Can any body give me proper suggestion with steps. If possible please give some sample JUnit code to test that.

Thanks,
RK

Comment: If your SQL code is generic and could be run across other databases, you can checkout the derby-maven-plugin and my answer to this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731178/creating-temporary-database-that-works-across-maven-test-phases/15089028#15089028.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at DBUnit - their how-to is at http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html

It does exactly what you're looking for.

The DBunit site has lots of examples. What I do is the following:

set up the d/b in the @Before method, so each test gets a clean fixture. An example of the @Before method is:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        try {
            IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(conn);
            DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig();
            config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
                    new HsqldbDataTypeFactory());
            DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, loadDutyData());
            DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT
                    .execute(connection, loadHelperData());
        } finally {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(conn, dataSource);
        }
```

where the loadHelperData() method does the folllowing:

```
DataFileLoader loader = new FlatXmlDataFileLoader();
        IDataSet ds = loader.load(TEST_DATA_FILE_HELPER);
        return ds;
```

The load method simply takes an xml file representing the database. See the DBUnit documentation for much more information.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

You could used [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) which is in memory database 100% JDBC API compatible.

To make JSON String from object you could use [Jacson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). So from jdbc resultset make your object then JSON string.

Comment: public JSONObject getResultById(int id) {
  Connection conn = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  String sqlQuery = "select * from " + table + " where id='"
    + id + "'";
  try {
      //get the connection
   conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
   //return result set in JSON format
   return getJsonString(rs);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   return null;
  } finally {
   try {
    if (conn != null)
     conn.close();
    if (stmt != null)
     stmt.close();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    return null;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: @user1321939, I did not get your comment. any problem?

Comment: mysql grouped query doesn work with HSQL db

Answer (score 0):

I like to add some code here:

```
    public JSONObject getResultById(int id) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String sqlQuery = "select * from " + table + " where id='"
            + id + "'";
    try {
        //get the connection
        conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        //return result set in JSON format
        return getJsonString(rs);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

To test this what will be best approach to test it. I some one give some sample JUnit test case then it will be very help full