# Keep Derby Network Server running after build

Tags: database, maven, derby

We are using a dependency to start a derby network server.
How can I start the derby network server so that it keeps running.
Now the server stops after the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731178/creating-temporary-database-that-works-across-maven-test-phases/15089028#15089028), you can use Derby as your database via the [derby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin) which I wrote and is available on GitHub and via Maven Central.

See [here](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin/blob/master/USAGE) for details on how to use it. This will basically remove the need for you to start Derby through your tests and it will keep it up and running while the tests are executing. In combination with the [sql-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/), you could have a reasonably decent testing environment.

To further clarify, the server does not run after the build has finished. However, under `target/derby` you can find your database which you can run, if you need to investigate the produced data.

Comment: This works for me, I can start derby by "mvn derby:start" and it keeps running, Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to file any bugs on Github.