# derby In memory database + junit

Tags: junit, derby, in-memory

I got an exception below when trying to use derby in memory database in JUNITTEST.

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database 'memory:testDB'
>   dropped.  at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:memory:testDB;create=true";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    super.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:memory:testDB;drop=true";
    DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
}
```

Comment: I assume the exception is occuring in your tearDown() method? It is normal for "drop=true" to throw a "Database dropped" exception. Is that what your question is about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven for your build, you can use the [derby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin), which I wrote and is available on GitHub and via Maven Central. It will take care of starting and stopping the database for you before your tests.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731178/creating-temporary-database-that-works-across-maven-test-phases/15089028#15089028) for my answer to a similar question.