# howto: in-memory derby db with glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, derby, javadb

I need run arquillian+junit tests on a remote Glassfish 4.1 server. The database tables for these test cases needs to be
(1) created **in-memory**,
(2) with **embedded JavaDB** and
(3) **dropped** after the test execution.

Would the following glassfish-resources.xml work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC
    "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
    "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedDerbyPool"
                   jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/chapter2" />
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="ArquillianEmbeddedDerbyPool"
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource"
                          is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false">
        <property name="databaseName" value="memory:action-bazaar-db"/>
        <property name="createDatabase" value="create"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

I did try it but not sure if the database is created in-memory. I keep getting the below error every time I run the tests. How to get rid of this error?

> PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE
>   (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15), PRIMARY KEY
>   (SEQ_NAME))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' already
>   exists in Schema 'APP'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven for your build, you can use the [derby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin), which I wrote and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin) and via Maven Central.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731178/creating-temporary-database-that-works-across-maven-test-phases/15089028#15089028) for my answer to a similar question.